# Codeigniter Unwanted line breaks before any content

Tags: php, codeigniter, line

I have noticed that i have 2 or 3 line breaks on each page source code before any content.
I checked utf-8 BOM on my some files but they are ok, i use netbeans so normally no problem no ?
Maybe some parent output or controller in CI is making it ?

These line breaks are breaking some servies requests ...

If you have any idea ...

Comment: Can you add an example of what you see/have?

Answer (score 0):

Check that none of your helpers, controllers, libraries or models contain a php end tag (?>) after the content as any whitespace there could be outputted.

If you can't locate the whitespace source, you could change the output file in the codeigniter core (system/core/Output.php). Locate the _display function, in that function before the check for compression, add: `$output = trim($output);`. In CI 2.1.4, this would be added at line 370. This will trim any whitespace from the start and end of your output.